# Resize the images on the client side in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, image-resizing

Is there any module which integrate with the image/file field module that allows me to resize the images on the client side in Drupal 7? My client has very big images and I prefer that he resizes them on the client side....

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Install [Plupload module for Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/plupload)

Edit the file plupload.module

Add `'resize' => array('width' => '320', 'height' => '240', 'quality' => '90'),` to #plupload_settings.

Example:

```
$element['filefield_plupload']['pud'] = array(
      '#type' => 'plupload',
      '#title' => t('Select one or more files to upload'),
      // Even though filefield does validation on submit, this is required for
      // client side validation as well as proper file munging during upload.
      '#upload_validators' => $element['#upload_validators'],
      '#plupload_settings' => array(
          'cardinality' => $field['cardinality'],
          'resize' => array('width' => '320', 'height' => '240', 'quality' => '90'),
```

Ref: Drupal Issue: [plupload client side resize option](https://www.drupal.org/node/2080945)

Answer (score 0):

[Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) has that functionality:

> Allows you to upload files using HTML5 Gears, Silverlight, Flash, BrowserPlus or normal forms, providing some unique features such as upload progress, image resizing and chunked uploads.

Handily enough a [Plupload module for Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/plupload) already exists.

Comment: I know about it, but there is no setting or config page which has to do with the resizing on the client side.